# Increase and decrease AWS instances CPUs automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

is there's a way in AWS to increase and decrease instances CPUs depending on pressure. I have been paying a lot of money for AWS statically increasing and decreasing instance cores when no clients are using it.
to be more specific, clients can upload an excel file and the software will do some calculations that will take time depending on the AWS instance cores. Having 2 cores will take 30 minutes to completion and having 96 cores will take only a couple of minutes.

Is there's a way to automatically increase the cores to 96 when the clients are using and uploading files to the website and automatically decrease the cores to 2 when no action is happening and clients are either not using the website or just using the website with current data and aren't taking a new action.

If not then can I possibly add a schedule in AWS to change the instance type. As an example run the instance on a 2 core type (ex: t2.large) and then change the instance type only from 1pm-6pm to 96 cores (ex: c5a.24xlarge) after that get it back to 2 cores?

I'm very new to AWS and devops in general, and I have been reading about AWS Autoscaling groups, but I'm not sure if this is the answer for my problem.

Comment: It depends on how your application is designed. If it is a web application, using EKS or Auto Scaling Group is your best bet. EKS uses a container and ASG can work with EC2 images.

Comment: If your objective is to save cost. You can consider creating auto scaling group of EC2 instances using Spot instances. Spot instances are very much cheaper compared with on-demand instances. But there are few downsides as well like AWS might revoke the spot instances real time hence need to handle that scenario separately. Check if this helps, https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/ec2-auto-scaling-spot-instances/

Comment: You definitely need autoscaling. You can't change the cpu but you can increase instances based on some metric you define. Select a basic instance for the minimum load/requests and increase the instances based on your need. It's quite simple as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to "scale CPU cores". (Commonly known as **Vertical scaling**.)

Instead, the recommended method is to **add/remove parallel capacity** based upon demand.

If you are using **Amazon EC2**, then you can launch more instances or terminate existing instances. This can be automated through [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html), which can monitor metrics (eg CPU Utilization) and then launch/terminate instances automatically. You would typically put a Load Balancer in front of these instances if they are web servers, or the instances might be 'worker nodes' that pull work from a queue.

If you are using **containers** (Docker, Kubernetes) then Amazon ECS/Amazon EKS can automatically add/remove tasks to meet demand for your application.

If you are using **AWS Lambda functions**, then they 'scale' by allowing multiple functions to run in parallel. Lambda functions typically exit when they have finished processing, so there is not charge when there is nothing to process.

These are all examples of **Horizontal scaling**, where capacity is **added/removed in parallel**.

Comment: Thank you John for the detailed answer,
If  "Vertical Scaling" is not possible then can I possibly add a schedule in AWS to change the instance type. As an example run the instance on a 2 core type (ex: t2.large) and change the instance type from 1pm-6pm to 96 cores (ex: c5a.24xlarge) after that get it back to 2 cores?

Comment: "Changing an instance type" is another form of Vertical Scaling. It is not supported. It would also interrupt your system since an instance would need to be stopped and a new one launched. AWS focuses on **horizontal scaling**, launching and terminating new instance capacity. If your system is designed to handle parallel compute, you could launch a new (larger) instance and then terminate the old instance, but you would need a way of redistribution the traffic/work amongst those instances. If your architecture can do this, then you might as well just do Horizontal Scaling.